# javascript change object's property and return it

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I have to change a object's property and keep all other properties. After the change, I need to push the object into an array. However, because of asynchronous issue (this is my guess), the value pushed is still the initial object. How can I solve the problem? Here is my code:

```
layer.features.forEach(function(feature){
  var geometry = feature.geometry;
  var igeometry = geometry.transform("EPSG:4326");
  feature.geometry = igeometry;
  myFeature.push(feature);
});
```

In the code, the feature pushed into myFeature[] is always the initial feature with geometry instead of new feature with igeometry.

Comment: Where do you access myFeature?

Comment: Here is the issue. myFeature is an output object's property, which must be outputed. No function use it as an input. @Jonasw

Comment: replace myFeature.push(feature); with "console.log(feature)" and verify if it's right, I don't believe that the problem there is async call

Comment: Theres no issue. Your code works properly... ( if feature.geometry is writable ...)

Comment: The code can only be run in a geoserver scripting environment, which doesn't allow me to console.log anything. That's why I can not debug it. Why there is no async call issue? The geometry.transform takes a while. Before it is done, the feature is already pushed into myFeature. I think the logic makes sense.

Comment: Yes feature.geometry might not be readable. It is not specified by their API. If there is no async issue, this must be the problem. But why there is not async issue? The geometry.transform takes a while. Before it is done, the feature is already pushed into myFeature. I think the logic makes sense. @Jonasw

Comment: Nope. Async !== long time. If its async, feature.geometry would be a promise. If not, theres no async code...

Comment: How can I identify if a code is async or not? Could you please explain this deeply? Or some useful link would be helpful. @Jonasw

Comment: Its async if its based on callbacks, or returns a promise.( E.g: setTimeout(alert,1) ) Else its not.

Comment: Let's use a simpler example. var a = 1;
var b = 2;
function plus (a, b, callback) {
 setTimeout(function(){a = a + b;}, 3000);
 console.log(a);
} In this example, console.log(a) is excuted before setTimeout(). From my understand, this is asynchronous. Although it doesn't use callback or promise. I believe callback and promise are two tools dealing with asynchronous issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to log to console geometry, igeometry, feature and make sure that they are all your expected value. From looking at your code it should work. So for example.
https://repl.it/INoA

```
let arr = [{a: 1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}];
function wait(item) {
    return new Promise (resolve => {
        item.a = item.a + 1;
        setTimeout(resolve, 100, item);
    });
}
let newArr = arr.map(item => {
   return wait(item);
});

Promise.all(newArr).then(values => {
    console.log(values);
});
```

You have a couple of options for your promises. You can either resolve it inside the promise, or you can use the new await method in which does the same thing.

```
http.get('someGetAddres').then(result => {
var myFeature = [];
layer.features.forEach(function(feature){
        var geometry = feature.geometry;
        var igeometry = geometry.transform("EPSG:4326");
        feature.geometry = igeometry;
        myFeature.push(feature);
    });
});

async function getFeature() {
    var layer = await http.get('myWebsite');
    var myFeature = [];
    layer.features.forEach(function(feature){
        var geometry = feature.geometry;
        var igeometry = geometry.transform("EPSG:4326");
        feature.geometry = igeometry;
        myFeature.push(feature);
    });
}
```

Comment: According to some comments, I guess the problem is probably caused by feature.geometry being read-only. They don't have specification in API. And the code can only be ran in geoserver scripting environment, which doesn't allow me to console.log(). Could you explain why there is no issue of asynchronous in my code?

Comment: In the example you gave, the final result is [2, 3, 4, 5] which is expected. However, after I added a 3 secs timeout to item.a = item.a + 1, the asynchronous issue raised. The result became [1, 2, 3, 4]. In my code, geometry.transform is a long-time call, which have the asynchronous issue.

Comment: So geometry.transform is an async function? Use promise all in this instance.

Comment: No, it's not. I believe the function actually worked. But I still curious about mechanism of asynchronous. Could you explain the issue I posted in the comment? The function is not asynchronous. When I add a timeout, the asynchronous issue exist. Why?

Comment: If your code has a combination of synchronous and async code. Then you need to be careful about how you write it so that code gets call in the order that you intend. A promise need to be resolved before you do something with that value. See example https://repl.it/IOBt

Comment: So once I add a timeout, the particular part of code becomes asynchronous. Is this correct?

Comment: Adding a timeout doesn't make it async. You could do a timeout synchronously. Async is basically saying do this thing say wait for 5 seconds, when it is done then fire a call back function which I have defined. The promise library wraps some helper functions around the call back like then and catch so you don't have to nest promises

Comment: From my understand, asynchronous is a style of executing codes. But based on your statement, asynchronous is a method dealing with asynchronous issue. Callback and promise are two methods solving asynchronous problem. Javascript always have synchronous issue. I can call a code asynchronous only each of the methods is applied to it. Do I understand you right?

Comment: I posted another question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145981/javascript-code-running-in-wrong-sequence