# Javascript code running in wrong sequence

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, promise

I have code like this:

```
var newArr = [];
var arr = [{a: 1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}];
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  setTimeout(function(){item.a = item.a + 1;}, 3000);
  newArr.push(item.a);
});
console.log(newArr);
```

The result is [1, 2, 3, 4] because of asynchronous. What's the promise and callback way to let it log [2, 3, 4, 5]?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear whether you were using the timeout to substitute some asynch behavior or whether the timeout is integral to what you're trying to solve. We'll get to them both. I'd written about turning `setTimeout()` into a promises pattern, in my [blog](https://cachecrew.com/promises-promises-timeout). So, first, turn use of `setTimeout()` into a promise-based pattern:

```
function timeout(delay) {
    return new Promise( 
       (resolve, reject) => setTimeout( resolve, delay )
    )
} // timeout()
```

So, step one (kind of) accomplishes what you want:

```
arr.forEach(function(item) {
   timeout(3000)
      .then(() => { 
         item.a = item.a + 1; 
         newArr.push(item.a) 
      });
   });
console.log(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2], arr[3]);  
console.log(newArr);
```

But notice, that immediately after completion of the `forEach()` call, `arr` and `newArr` have their old values. *Eventually*, they'll be updated. When can we use updated `arr` and `newArr`? We need to wait until the values are updated.

```
var promises=[]
arr.forEach(function(item) {

  promises.push(timeout(3000)
    .then(() => { 
            item.a = item.a + 1; 
            newArr.push(item.a) 
        })
    )
});

Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log(arr, newArr))
```

Collect up the promises and wait on them to all finish... then you know they are "up to date".

Comment: What I am trying to do is make the function item.a = item.a + 1 as long-time process. So setTimeout and the function can not be separated. You have to treat it as a whole part. What I want to know is if there is way to make a long-time function in synchronous style (without promise or callback like item.a = item.a + 1) be executed before it's result is called (newArr.push(item.a)).

Comment: I am not quite clear about your requirements. You'd mentioned, in the original question that you wanted a Promise-based solution. I have preserved the incrementing of `item.a` as a delayed process. The increment in my solution occurs after 3 seconds, as in your question. Is it the `newArr.push()` that you want to keep separate from `item.a++`? If so, you can move the `newArr.push()` to the `Promise.all()` handler.

Comment: That is: move the `newArr.push()` from the timeout handler to `Promise.all(promises).then(() => { arr.forEach( item => newArr.push(item.a) ) }`

Comment: I know it's really confusing. Let's forget timeout at first. If have the code item.a = item.a + 1; newArr.push(item.a);. I can get the newArr with updated values with no doubt. However, if item.a + 1 cost a long time to process, newArr.push(item.a) would be executed before item.a + 1 is done. Therefore, we will get newArr with old values. I tried to ask how to make sure item.a + 1 is always done before newArr.push() is executed, even if item.a + 1 cost a long time.

Comment: @zhangjinzhou "*item.a + 1 cost a long time to process, newArr.push(item.a) would be executed before item.a + 1 is done*" - that's not exactly what your current code is showing. If the increment is synchronous, you have no problems; if the increment is asynchronous it needs to take a callback like the `setTimeout` did. Regardless of the exact situation, put the asynchronous code in a function that returns a promise.

Comment: @zhangjinzhou If I understand your last comment, I think that is what my previous comment suggested (i.e., move the `newArr.push()` call until we _know_ that the data has been updated). Perhaps I am still not understanding. Promises allows you to write synchronous-looking code by separating them into callbacks—Promises _synchronizes_ execution for you. :-)

Comment: It looks like the situation I assumed is not a typical async practice. To be honest, I have never see a example in real life yet. Two of other answers give the solution however they are not callback or promise. I appreciate you help and patience!

Comment: You're welcome. If you wouldn't mind, could you please mark this answer as answered, if indeed it did answer your original question?

Answer (score 1):

You would do it like this:

Create a function that takes two parameters:   `a` and  `arr` and 'newArr' representing the array and a  and newArr variables.

This function would act as a recursive function which would set a timeout  and then call itself again like this:

```js
var arr = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}, {a: 4}];
var newArr = [];
var a = 0;

function recursiveIterator(a, arr, newArr) {
  var b = a;
  b++;
  var newerArr = newArr;
  if (b < arr.length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      newerArr.push(arr[b].a);
      recursiveIterator(b, arr, newerArr);
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    console.log(newerArr);
  }
}

recursiveIterator(a, arr, newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Rid of the setTimeout. [REPL](https://repl.it/IOHp/0)

```
var newArr = [];
var arr = [{a: 1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}];
arr.forEach(function(item) {
    item.a = item.a + 1;
    newArr.push(item.a);
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: You beat me to it

Comment: The setTimeout must be there. What I am trying to do is make the function item.a = item.a + 1 as long-time process.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the increment before the timeout

```js
var newArr = [];
var arr = [{a: 1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}];
var itemsProcessed = 0;

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  setTimeout(function(){item.a = item.a+1;newArr.push(item.a);
  itemsProcessed++;
  if(itemsProcessed === arr.length) {
      console.log(newArr);
    }
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: The setTimeout must be there. What I am trying to do is make the function item.a = item.a + 1 as long-time process.

Comment: @zhangjinzhou I have updated your with timeout function, Please check.

Comment: setTimeout and item.a = item.a + 1 must be a whole part. I want them to represent some long-time call in synchronous style.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your code synchronously via [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs):

Here is how your code may look like:

```
var longRunningFunction = function(ctx,timeout,val) {
    var ret={};
    setTimeout(function(){
        ret.result = val + 1;
        ctx.resume();
    },timeout);
    return ret;
};
longRunningFunction.nsynjsHasCallback = true;

function myFunc() {
    var newArr = [];
    var arr = [{a: 1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}];
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var item=arr[i];
        item.a = longRunningFunction(nsynjsCtx,1000,item.a).result;
        newArr.push(item.a);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr));
}
nsynjs.run(myFunc,{},function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

Resulting output will be printed with 4 seconds delay:

```
[2,3,4,5]
```